# Changing value of class variable python3

Tags: python, class, methods

Hello im on my journey to understand classes in python, so to make it more fun im trying to make basic text rpg game. Right now im trying to make function which take instance of class as argument and is changing specific attribute of it for example:

```
class short_sword:
def __init__(self):
    self.modf = 1
    self.name = "Short Sword"
    self.min_dmg = 1 * self.modf
    self.max_dmg = 3 * self.modf
    self.group = 0
```

Now im trying to change self.modf value by using function on instance of that class:

```
def jewel(short_sword):
    short_sword.modf = short_sword.modf + 1
```

After that im creating object and printing values min_dmg and max_dmg before and after usage of that function to check if its works:

```
item = short_sword(1)
print(str(item.min_dmg))
print(str(item.max_dmg))
jewel(item)
print(str(item.min_dmg))
print(str(item.max_dmg))
```

but its stays the same 1 for min_dmg and 3 for max_dmg nothing is getting changed, how can i access that variable by function to change it?
English is not my native language so i hope that somebody will understand me Sorry for trouble and thanks for help :P

Comment: You seem confused between classes and instances of classes.

Comment: Little bit thats why im trying to use classes in everything to face problems that hopefully will allow me to understand it better :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you update your `modf` you don't update `min_dmg` and `max_dmg`. You could use an accessor:

```
class short_sword:
    def __init__(self):
        self.modf = 1
        self.name = "Short Sword"
        self.min_dmg = 1 * self.modf
        self.max_dmg = 3 * self.modf
        self.group = 0

    def change_modf(self, newValue):
        self.modf = newValue
        self.processDmg()

    def processDmg(self):
        self.min_dmg = 1 * self.modf
        self.max_dmg = 3 * self.modf
```

And then

```
def jewel(short_sword):
    short_sword.change_modf(short_sword.modf + 1)
```

Because otherwise your properties still have their initial value.

Side note: you use

```
item = short_sword(1)
```

But your `short_sword` class doesn't take any argument in its constructor... What is the 1 supposed to be useful for?

Comment: Oww its working. Thank You for Your help and time :] about that short_sword(1) it was in previous version which takes input to set modf i forgot to delete that